# How to Access 2nd div of parent > child that have identical classes with CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to access the 2nd "hello" `<div>`.
I've tried `nth-child`, `nth-type`, but nothing works.

```css
.hello:nth-of-type(1) select {
  background-color: blue;
}

.hello:nth-of-type(2) select {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">
  <select>
    <option>1st</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="hello">
  <select>
    <option>2nd</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: please add the code that you have tried

Comment: from the top of my head: `.hello:nth-child(2) { .... }`

Comment: @RenevanderLende Pseudo classes match elements, not classes of elements. Adding a class makes it act more like a filter

Comment: @j08691 not entirely sure what you mean, just checked this and seems to work in FF. And isn't filtering just what is needed: ignore everthing but .hello-2? Just being curious...

Comment: no idea, I'm pretty rusty at CSS. first time using nth-of-type

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nth-child` or also `nth-of-type`. Here a example with **nth-child**:

```css
div.hello:nth-child(1) select{
 background-color: blue;
}

div.hello:nth-child(2) select{
 background-color: green;
}

div.hello:nth-child(3) select{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="hello">
  <select>
    <option>1st</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="hello">
  <select>
    <option>2nd</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="hello">
  <select>
    <option>3nd</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this I and I expect that to work, but when I add the code it turns them all the same color even though I specified different colors.

Comment: @AD i have changed it now... look all three hello-classes have differently colors

Comment: Yes that's exactly how I added it with different colors but still they're staying the same color, that's what's so strange. Maybe it's something in wordpress that I'm using.